# Trying to Implement gauge.js on Vue Js but not success

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to Implement gauge.js in Vue JS Application.

```
 <template>
   <gauge-js level="90" marks="1,2,3" aperture="240" colors="80:#f8f3bc,100:#eee"></gauge-js>
 </template>


import Vue from 'vue'
import gauge from 'gauge-js'
Vue.component('gauge-js', gauge)
```

What I'm trying to do like:

```
  export default gauge.extend({
  props: [ 'data', 'marks' ],
  mounted () {

    level: 67;
    marks: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
    length: 400;
 }
```

But while import the js library of gauge.js it's showing out of stack memory size.
Also I cann't extend [gauge.js](https://github.com/bernii/gauge.js) library.

If anyone can help me then I will be grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example in jsfiddle or codepen for example

Comment: Please share your code: it is unclear to what you have actually tried, and therefore it is very difficult to help. See: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello @Eylen, here's jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/96x2142c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast and dirty example so you can continue working:
https://jsfiddle.net/96x2142c/2/

I have created a new component and I'm using it in the vue app.

```
Vue.component('gauge-js', {
    props: ["level","marks","aperture","colors"],
    template: "<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>",
    mounted () {
      var opts = {
        angle: 0.15, /// The span of the gauge arc
        lineWidth: 0.44, // The line thickness
        pointer: {
          length: 0.9, // Relative to gauge radius
          strokeWidth: 0.035 // The thickness
        },
        colorStart: '#6FADCF',   // Colors
        colorStop: '#8FC0DA',    // just experiment with them
        strokeColor: '#E0E0E0'   // to see which ones work best for you
      };
      var target = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); // your canvas element
      var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
      gauge.maxValue = 3000; // set max gauge value
      gauge.setMinValue(0);  // set min value
      gauge.set(1250); // set actual value
   }
})

new Vue({
    el:"#app",
})
```

Comment: Hello @Eylen, your solution works perfectly. Only I'm having problem with dynamic Template ID. How can I take ID's from "props"? template: "<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>". Props aren't working here.

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/soouuz0r/ I've commented on <gauge-js/> what I want to do.

Comment: Hello, here you have my example updated so you can get the id from props passed to the component: https://jsfiddle.net/96x2142c/4/. Take care with kebab-case in the props

Comment: Worked, perfectly. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: You have defined certain props but why if you aren't using them?

Comment: @Eylen that was exactly what I was looking for, but how to change value of the gauge dynamically?